# python __new__ - how to implement when not subclassing

Tags: python

**Part A**

I want to do some checking on arguments to a class instantiation and possibly return `None` if it doesn't make sense to even create the object.

I've read the docs but I don't understand **what to return** in this case.

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, Param):
        if Param == 5:
            return None
        else:
            # What should 'X' be?
            return X
```

What should `X` be in `return X`?

- It cannot be `self` because the object doesn't exist yet so `self` is not a valid keyword in this context.

**Part B**

Tied to my question, I don't understand the **need** to have the `cls` parameter.

If you call the constructor of `MyClass` - `var = MyClass(1)` - won't `cls` always be `MyClass`?
How could it be anything else?

According to the docs, `cls` in `object.__new__(cls[, ...])` is:

> [. . .the class of which an instance was requested as its first
>   argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Comment: You are most probably better off raising an exception than returning `None`.

Comment: @DeepSpace noted. But it may make sense to return `None` in some cases.

Comment: It's ok, as long as you remember that.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are using Python 3 because you provided a link to Python 3 docs)

`X` could be `super().__new__(cls)`.

`super()` returns the parent class (in this case it is simply `object`). Most of the times when you are overriding methods you will need to call the parent class's method at some point.

See this example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, param):
        if param == 5:
            return None
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
```

And then:

```
a = MyClass(1)

print(a)
print(a.param)

>> <__main__.MyClass object at 0x00000000038964A8>
1

b = MyClass(5)

print(b)
print(b.param)

>> None
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
   print(b.param)
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'param'
```

Comment: What does `super()` return?

Comment: I've read [the doc on super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) but I'm hopelessly confused.

Comment: @Adrian `super()` returns the parent class, in this case `object`. I assumed  you are using Python 3, is that correct?

Comment: I believe that and it makes sense but I'm trying to find THAT info in the [`super()` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) and cannot.

Comment: `super([type[, object-or-type]])` - "Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type." What does that mean? I can't figure out what "proxy object" means.

Comment: @Adrian Read a little further :) "This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.". `super()` simply provides access to the parent class's attributes.

Comment: What does "proxy object" mean? What does this mean: "If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound."

Comment: [In order for `__init__` to be called, I have to return an instance of `cls`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). How does `return super().__new__(cls)` return an instance of `cls`?

Comment: @Adrian calling `super().__new__(cls)`  has the exact same consequences as if we didn't override `__new__` at all. It just proceeds and creates the object and returns it.

Comment: Ok I get that, like a default constructor call in C++. But specific to Python, how does `super().__new__(cls)` return a `cls` object so that `__init__` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the instance of cls like this `return object.__ new__(cls)`. Because every class is subclass of `object`, you can use that as a object creator for your class. The returnes object is passed as a first argument to the `__init__()` with the any number of positional argument or any number of keyword argument you passed to new. There you will create instance variable assigning those values.

Comment: How does that return an instance of `cls`? [That's the requirement for `__init__` to be called.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Comment: That question was like how python creates an object. For every objcet creation, before __init__() ,__new__() is called. Refer to this page, this may give you a clear idea. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence

Comment: ". . .the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument." this means name of the class. if you print the `cls`, it will print it as `__main__.MyClassName`